# C++ relational operators generator

Tags: c++, templates

Once you define the `<` operator, you can have an estimation of how the rest of relational operators behave. I'm trying to implement a way to do that for my classes.

What I want is to define only the `<` and the rest of the operators to be defaulted implicitly. What I've got so far is this design, which I'll elaborate on further down:

```
template<typename T>
struct relational
{
    friend bool operator> (T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return rhs < lhs; }
    friend bool operator==(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(lhs < rhs || lhs > rhs); }
    friend bool operator!=(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(rhs == lhs); }
    friend bool operator<=(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(rhs < lhs); }
    friend bool operator>=(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(lhs < rhs); }
};
```

So for a class that implements the `<` operator it would just take inheriting from `relational` to have the rest of the operators defaulted.

```
struct foo : relational<foo>
{ 
    // implement < operator here
};
```

1. Are there any alternatives, better designs ?
2. Is there a time bomb in this code? I'm assuming that if a user wants to define a custom implementation for one of the operators, the overload resolution would kick and select the non template (user defined) implementation. If that's not the case (or I would have problem with class templates inheriting from `relational`) should I implement the operators in `relational` like this ?

   ```
   // inside the relational struct
   friend bool operator>(relational const &lhs, relational const &rhs)
   { // functions that involve implicit conversion are less favourable in overload resolution
           return (T const&)rhs < (T const&)lhs; 
   }
   ```

Thanks for your advices, here's a [demo of the code working](http://ideone.com/Ck7Z6k)

Comment: You should note, that friend relationships are not inherited. I don't know if this might hit you at some point.

Comment: Side note: rhs means "right hand side" and lhs means "left hand side". It seems that your function parameters are named inversely. Also, while defining `operator ==` in terms of `operator <` may be mathematically interesting, it's most likely not performance-friendly, since you call `operator <` twice while the actual operation is probably very similar to a single `operator ==`.

Comment: 1. You're partly duplicating [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) and [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp). 2. You'll find more clients if you allow 2 primitive operations: `<` and `==`. There are cases where `<` ordering is not total, i.e. it's possible that `!(a<b) && !(a>b) && a!=b`.

Comment: @Angew The clients will only be classes you write yourself (or that people who know the existence of this class write), so you can go even further, and use named functions.  Why privilege `<`?

Comment: @JamesKanze Because that's what `std::rel_ops` does :-) But you're right of course there's no fundamental reason for it, as you demonstrate in your answer (which I've upvoted).

Comment: @Shahbaz thnx for the comment, I updated the question

Comment: @Angew If you'd posted this comment as answer i'd have accepted it. It's the best design and most reusable code (damn it once again I thought I had discovered the wheel ... )

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou It would have been a pretty much link-only answer. I think it's fine as a comment, and James has given a great answer for situations where you don't want to (or can't) bring in Boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use a trick I learned from Robert Martin to do this.
I have a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class ComparisonOperators
{
protected:
    ~ComparisonOperators() {}

public:
    friend bool operator==( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) == 0;
    }
    friend bool operator!=( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) != 0;
    }
    friend bool operator<( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) < 0;
    }
    friend bool operator<=( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) <= 0;
    }
    friend bool operator>( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) > 0;
    }
    friend bool operator>=( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare( rhs ) >= 0;
    }
};
```

The class which needs the operators derives from this:

```
class Toto : public ComparisonOperators<Toto>
{
    // ...
public:
    //      returns value < 0, == 0 or >0, according to
    //      whether this is <, == or > other.
    int compare( Toto const& other ) const;
};
```

(My implementation is actually a bit more complicated, since it
uses some simple meta-programming to call `isEqual`, rather than
`compare`, if that function exists.)

EDIT:

And rereading your question: this is basically what you're doing, and it's pretty much the standard idiom for this sort of thing.  I prefer using named functions like `compare`, but that is just a personal preference.  The meta-programming trick to handle `isEqual`, however, is worth the bother: it means that you can use the same class for types which only support equality; you'll get an error when the compiler tries to instantiate e.g. `operator<=`, but the compiler won't try to instantiate it unless someone uses it.  And it's often the case the `isEqual` can be implemented a lot more efficiently than `compare`.

EDIT 2:

For what it's worth: I do this systematically.  I also have
`ArithmeticOperators` (defining e.g. `+` in terms of `+=`),
`MixedTypeArithmeticOperators` (like the above, but with two
types, `T1`, for which it is a base class, and `T2`; it
provides all of the combination of operators).  and
`STLIteratorOperators`, which implements the STL iterator
interface based on something more rational and easier to
implement (basically, the GoF iterator with an `isEqual`
function).  They saves a lot of boilerplate.

EDIT 3:

And finally: I just looked at the actual code in my toolkit.
Conditionally supporting `isEqual` is even simpler than
I remembered: the template class above has a public member:

```
bool isEqual( T const& other ) const
{
    return static_cast< T const* >( this )->compare( other ) == 0;
}
```

And `operator==` and `operator!=` just use `isEqual`, no
template meta-programming involved.  If the derived class
defines an `isEqual`, it hides this one, and it gets used.  If
not, this one gets used.

Comment: For the `STLIteratorOperators` thing, what about just `boost::iterator_facade`?

Comment: @Xeo It wasn't around when I wrote `STLIteratorOperators`.  I suspect that it does provide the same functionality, but probably with some additional complexity.  (I've found that adding Boost to a project can increase build times significantly.)

Comment: Ofcourse the protected destructor! Avoids messed up destruction if one  deletes though a pointer to base class. This addition and the extension with `compare` justify a +1 and accepted answer.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou With regards to the protected destructor, yes.  In practice, it's hard to imagine someone ever having a pointer to the base class, much less deleting through it, but the protected destructor is close to free (and in C++11, with `= default`, is free), so why not add the protection.

Answer (score 1):

friends are not inherited, so this idea won't work. However, you may cleverly use macro instead for example:

```
#define GEN(X) \
    friend bool operator> (T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return rhs < lhs; } \
    friend bool operator==(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(lhs < rhs || lhs > rhs); } \
    friend bool operator!=(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(rhs == lhs); } \
    friend bool operator<=(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(rhs < lhs); } \
    friend bool operator>=(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return !(lhs < rhs); }
```

And you may use as:

```
class Foo
{
...
GEN(foo)
};
```

Comment: Since friendship, here, is not for access, but simply to allow defining a non-member function inline in the class definition, I don't see why the problem.

Comment: Because you are trying to inherit and that's not exactly inlining

Comment: There's nothing illegal in inheriting here.  And since `T::operator<` is public, the function can access it, even if it isn't a friend of `T`.  The reason the operators in his example were declared `friend` is because this is the only way you can provide the implementation of a non-member function in a class definition.

Comment: @JamesKanze What you said, and I'd like to add one thing. The friendship there is common idiom named "friend injection" (or something). What it does is cause the generation of the function when a type is instantiated. This answer is not what I was looking for, but it works and got a +1 from me!

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou It's called friend name injection (not in the standard, but generally).  It's a bit complex to understand: the _name_ of the friend function is declared in the surrounding namespace, but it is not made visible there; it can only be found by ADL, which looks in the class definition (including base classes).