# pass operators overloadings as templates parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

i am writing a augmented binary search tree class. i finished the simple version with integers and now i would like to impliment the same structure with templates. the problem i encounter is the following.
 I need to have a tree filled with objects from a library that i can't change. Those objects do not have the greater operator that i am currently using for my tree implementation. how can i do that?
 
the Tree.h file has a struct node which contains all the information of a node or a leaf and the actual Tree code

struct node

```
template <typename keytype>
class 
template <typename keytype >
struct Node {
    //key value
    keytype key;
    //node type , leaf ot internal Node
    bool leaf;
    //childern pointers
    struct Node<keytype>* left;
    struct Node<keytype>* right;
    //height of tree 
    int height;
    //ansestor
    struct Node<keytype>* ansestor;
};



template <typename item>
class Tree{
public:
Tree();                                     //tree constructor

void insert(item key);                      //inserts a new element 

bool remove(item key);                      //remove an existing element

void printInOrder();                        //print tree in order

int getHeight();                            //returns the height of the tree

Node<item> getFirst();                          //returns the first element of tree-list 

Node<item> getLast();                               //returns the last element of tree-list

Node<item> getNext();                               //returns the next value of the last accessed element

Node<item> getPrevious();                           //returns the privious value of the last accessed element

private:

int height,
    numOfElements;

Node<item>* root;

Node<item>* listPosition;                           //internal pointer, points to an element in the list

/***************************private functions**********************/

void _insert(Node<item> *&newNode, item &key);      //private insertion function

bool _remove(Node<item> *&currentNode,item &key);   //remove the leaf with key is it exists

void _balanceTree(Node<item> *&currentNode);        //balance the tree if needed

void _rotateLeft(Node<item> *&root);                //performs a left rotation

void _rotateRight(Node<item> *&root);               //performs a right rotation

Node<item>* _createNewNode(const item &key,     //alocates memeory space for new leaf/node
    const bool &leaf=true,                      //and passes it defaults or given values
    Node<item>* left=NULL, Node<item>* right=NULL,
    const int &height=0, Node<item>* ansestor=NULL);

void _updateHeight(Node<item> *&currentNode);       //updates the height of a node 

void _inOrderTraversal(Node<item>* currentNode);    //print in order function

void _printNodesInfo(Node<item>* currentNode);  //print node function

bool _removeLeft(Node<item> *&parent);          //removes the left child of a internal node

bool _removeRight(Node<item> *&parent);         //removes the right chold of a internal node

Node<item> _getFirst(Node<item> *root);                 //returns the value of the first item and 
                                            //sets the internal pointer to that element 

Node<item> _getLast(Node<item> *root);                  //returns the value of the last item and 
                                            //sets the internal pointer to that element 

Node<item>* _next(Node<item> *leaf);                    //returns a pointer to leaf's next element and
                                            //sets the internal pointer to that element 

Node<item>* _previous(Node<item> *leaf);                //returns a poiunter to leaf's previous element and
                                            //sets the internal pointer to that element
```

};

when i want to do insertions etc to find the location of a node, i compare keys by using the following code

```
if (key>currentNode->key)
    {
        if (DEBUG){
            cout<<">>>>>>>>>>>>>>go right>>>>>>>>>"<<endl;
        }
        this->_insert(currentNode->right,key);
    }
    else
    {
        if (DEBUG){
            cout<<"<<<<<<<<<<<<<go left<<<<<<<<<<<"<<endl;
        }
        this->_insert(currentNode->left,key);
    }
```

which is part of function _insert

```
template <typename item>
void Tree<item>::_insert(Node<item> *&currentNode, item &key){

if (this->root==NULL)
{/*the tree is empty at this point*/
    if (DEBUG){
        cout<<"tree was empty"<<endl;
    }
    /*inititialize the root*/

    root= this->_createNewNode(key,true);
    this->numOfElements=1;
    return;


}
else if (currentNode->height==0)//currentNode->leaf==true
{//we reached a leaf 
    if (DEBUG){
        cout<<"-------insertion found-----"<<endl;
    }
    Node<item>* oldLeaf= currentNode;                       //keep the pointer to the old leaf
    Node<item>* privious;

    currentNode= this->_createNewNode(654, false);  //create a new internal node and link it to the tree
    currentNode->height=1;                          //set its height to 1 

    Node<item>* newLeaf = _createNewNode(key, true); 

    if (newLeaf->key>oldLeaf->key)
    {/*the new leaf is the biggest element in the tree*/
        currentNode->right= newLeaf;
        currentNode->left= oldLeaf;

        //list connection
    }
    else
    {/*normal insertion*/
        currentNode->right= oldLeaf;
        currentNode->left= newLeaf;


        //list connection
        privious=this->_previous(oldLeaf);
        if (privious!=NULL){//old element was not the first one 
            privious->right=newLeaf;
            newLeaf->left=privious;
        }

    }
    currentNode->left->right=currentNode->right;
    currentNode->right->left=currentNode->left;

    currentNode->key= currentNode->left->key;
    currentNode->left->ansestor= currentNode;
    this->numOfElements++;
    return;
}
else
{/*search deeper to the tree*/
    if (key>currentNode->key)
    {
        if (DEBUG){
            cout<<">>>>>>>>>>>>>>go right>>>>>>>>>"<<endl;
        }
        this->_insert(currentNode->right,key);
    }
    else
    {
        if (DEBUG){
            cout<<"<<<<<<<<<<<<<go left<<<<<<<<<<<"<<endl;
        }
        this->_insert(currentNode->left,key);
    }
    //this balance tree
    this->_updateHeight(currentNode);
    this->_balanceTree(currentNode);        //balance the tree if needed
    this->_updateHeight(currentNode);

    //cout <<"-----------------test height is "<<currentNode->height<<endl;

    return;
}
}
```

now as i mentioned before this works if the key is something that has the greater operator(like int). how can i write the code to handle objects that dose not have this operator? 
e.g. if i need to fill the tree with a class that represents points and this class dose not support the greater operator. lets say that i want to store them based on x axis so a point p1(x1,y1) is greater than point p2(x2,y2) if x1>x2. i can write functions for something like that, but i dont know how to pass this function in the tree and how to keep the default comparison for objects like int.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing the definition of the `class` (as opposed to the `struct`), I believe. Also where is that function body in? What's `this`? What's `currentNode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at what STL does with associative containers, where this question has already been solved.

Take `std::set` for example (a binary search tree in essence), there the comparison function for `<` gets embedded in the type of the tree as the `comparator`. You can have :

```
// The comparison object
struct Comp
{
    bool operator()(int i1, int i2)
    {
        return i1 < i2;
    }
};
// using the comparison object as the comparator
std::set<int, Comp> lala;
```

Similarly you can have your Tree layout look like that

```
template <typename keytype, typename Comp>
struct Node
{
    ....
    friend bool operator<(Node const& left, Node const &right)
    { // Now your nodes know how to compare themselves
        return Comp(left, right);
    }
    ....
};

template <typename item, typename Comp>
class Tree
{
    ....
    Node<item, Comp> *root; 
    ....
};
```

Now, when writing code for your `Tree` member functions you can write

```
n1 < n2 ; // node1 < node2
```

and know they are being compared in terms of the comparator you specified as a template argument

---

As a bonus feature, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23388739/2567683) a way to have **all relational operators generated** for you once you **defined the `<` operator** (Actually the definition of a comparator is mandated by this design, so `Node` inheriting from `relational` will give you `>`, `>=`, `<=`, `==`, `!=` automatically generated)

```
template <typename keytype, typename Comp>
struct Node : relational<Node<keytype,Comp>>
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to use a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   /// no operator greater than
 public:
    int value() const;
}
```

You can define a nonmember operator > like this:

```
inline bool operator > (const MyClass & left, const MyClass & right)
{
   return left.value() > right.value();
}
```

Note this this does not need to be a member of the class so no modification to the class declaration is needed.   You are, however, restricted to using the public interface of the class to do the comparison (unless you modify the class to declare `operator >(...)` a friend, but in that case you could simply add a member `operator >(...)`.

Note that I had to edit my answer because I assumed the common idiom of using operator < for ordering (operator > works fine, but it is rare to find it used for this purpose.)

Comment: that helps a lot, but is it possible to overload the operator in every instance of the tree separately? lets say that one tree stores 2D points with respect to x axis and an other tree stores the same points but with respect to y axis. can i do something like this with templates?

Comment: The overload doesn't have anything to do with the trees. It is defining an operator > for MyClass objects.   If you want to use templates, you are welcome to, as long as you understand how they work.  If you don't want to use templates there is no particular need for them in this problem.