# Convert string to operator

Tags: c++, string, operators

I am implementing a basic interpreter function that simulates an "conditional jump".
It takes four inputs, which are

1. variable(Char type)
2. operator(<=, > ...)(String type)
3. integer value(int type)
4. line number(int type)

#### Function declaration

```
void ProgramState::conditionalJump(int var, std::string op, int immediate, int destination);
// condition: Compares var and immediate using op
// if condition is true: modify current address to destination if the
// if false: nothing happens
```

For example, I can write a very crude implementation that is shown below:

#### Example:

```
if ( (op == "<") && (var < immediate) ){
    cur_line = destination;
}
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? 
I thought about overloading the operator, but I am not sure if it works.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Is there a way to convert string type to operator type?

Comment: Can you post the signature of the function, explain what the arguments stand for, and what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: I think what you have there is about the simplest implementation

Comment: There is no such thing as "operator type", is it? You want something like `var (op) immediate`, where `op` is evaluated as operator between arguments. There is no such thing in C++; The only thing that you can do is to write what you already have in more convoluted way, arguably cleaner/more readable but in principle functionally the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are asking is how to convert a `std::string` to a `relational operator`. Well, I don't know any way to achieve this with metaprogramming, but the string class has only [6 relational operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/). So I would simply hard-code them into the function.

Example:

```
void conditionalJump(int var, std::string op, int immediate, int destination)
{
   if      ((op == "==") && (var == immediate))  cur_line = destination;
   else if ((op == "!=") && (var != immediate))  cur_line = destination;
   else if ((op == "<")  && (var < immediate))   cur_line = destination;
   else if ((op == ">")  && (var > immediate))   cur_line = destination;
   else if ((op == "<=") && (var <= immediate))  cur_line = destination;
   else if ((op == ">=") && (var >= immediate))  cur_line = destination;
}
```

If this wasn't what you were looking for, then my guess is that you might wanna checkout the following links:

- [C++ relational operators generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388739/c-relational-operators-generator)
- [Using character as relational operator in C/C++](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=816205&p=5100069#post5100069)

Answer (score 2):

What you literally asked to do isn't possible, C++ provides no means to "convert" data to code.

You can (arguably) improve on a series of separate tests with something like a map from strings to functors that do the comparisons.

Setup code:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<bool(int, int)> comparisons;
comparisons["<"] = std::less<int>();
comparisons[">"] = std::greater<int>();
... etc ...
```

Usage code (not particularly efficient but concise version):

```
if (comparisons.count(op) && comparisons[op](var, immediate)) {
    cur_line = destination;
}
```

For performance you might want to use function pointers rather than `std::function` as the values in the map. You have to write more setup, though. And for that matter, the code you already have might well be faster.

Comment: if OP decides to go this route, here is the link for function objects: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/