# C++ is operator!= automatically provided when operator== defined

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I wonder if operator!= is automatically provided when operator== is defined within my class? When I have operator== defined in class A, obviously A a, A b, a == b works, but a != b doesn't. However I am not sure if it always happens. Are there any exceptions from this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading?rq=1

Comment: This might be possible in a future version of the language: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4114.htm

Comment: Related Q : [relational operators generator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23388739/2567683) (actually you only need `<` to have all of them)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The operator `!=` is *not* automatically provided for you. You may want to read about [rel_ops](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/rel_ops/) namespace if you want such automation. Essentially you can say

```
using namespace std::rel_ops;
```

before using `operator !=`.

Comment: But be careful to limit the scope of the using directive. It will provide operators for all types, not just the one you're interested in, which could have surprising consequences.

Answer (score 15):

No, operators (apart from assignment) are never automatically generated. It's easy enough to define it in terms of `==`:

```
bool operator!=(A const & l, A const & r) {return !(l == r);}
```

Comment: Please see ivan ukr answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is true since C++20. Earlier C++ standard versions do not provide operator!= from operator== automatically.

Comment: In C++20 and over, you should actually use the `<=>` operator then all the other 6 operators are defined in one swoop.

Comment: Except when you don't want `operator<` and `operator>`.

Comment: I'd say "you can" instead of "you should". That is true, in many cases you'll want to do so, but still not always. Sometimes you just don't need < and >, so you can have only operator==. Moreover, in C++20 you can have operator== defined as = default.

Answer (score 3):

What you're after isn't provided by the language for obvious reasons.  What you want *is* provided for by [`boost::operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm):

```
class MyClass : boost::operators<MyClass> {
    bool operator==(const MyInt& x) const;
}
```

will get you an `operator!=()` based on *your* `operator==()`

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You have to define it explicitly.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a
{
    private:
        int b;
    public:
        a(int B): b(B)
        bool operator == (const a & other) { return this->b == other.b; }
};

int main()
{
    a a1(10);
    a a2(15);
    if (a1 != a2)
    {
        cout << "Not equal" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[ djhaskin987@des-arch-danhas:~ ]$ g++ a.cpp
a.cpp: In constructor ‘a::a(int)’:
a.cpp:11:9: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘bool’
         bool operator == (const a & other) { return this->b == other.b; }
         ^
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:18:12: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘a’ and ‘a’)
     if (a1 != a2)
            ^
a.cpp:18:12: note: candidates are: ...
```

Comment: Please see ivan ukr answer

Answer (score 1):

If you `#include <utility>`, you can specify `using namespace std::rel_ops`.

Doing this will automatically define `operator !=` from `operator ==`, and `operator <=`,  `operator >=`,  `operator >` from `operator <`.

Comment: `std::rel_ops` is a bit... [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225375/idiomatic-use-of-stdrel-ops).

Answer (score 0):

No, != is not defined automatically in terms of ==.
There are some generics define in  that help to define all the operators in term of == and <,
though.